# Magento 2.3.0 Reset password page showing blank

Tags: magento2.3.0, password-recovery, forgot-password

For some reason in our 2.3.0 installation the admin's reset password page does not show the form.

There is nothing appearing in the Magento error logs or reports. Also server logs are not showing anything.

I re-deployed static files by force (I'm in developer mode) and cleared the caches.

Everything else seems to work.

Any ideas what could cause this?

[image: Reset password page form missing]

Comment: I have the same issue, did you find the solution ?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't remember anymore what caused this, but I think I got it fixed. Check your translation files and it's encoding and special characters at least, if you use them. Maybe also manually delete some static file folders etc.

Comment: I found something, the block displaying the form have the name="content" in the layout. If I change the name the block is displayed. I will juste redeclare the block with an other name on this page

Comment: @Taschert you have find any solution for that? please update answer here i am same issue facing in magento 2.3.2

Comment: @RakeshDonga I have just posted the answer

Answer (score 2):

I have created a Module and redeclared the layout for the forgotten password page

```
//File app/code/Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/layout/adminhtml_auth_resetpassword.xml

<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="login.content">
            <block class="Magento\Backend\Block\Template" name="contentt" template="Vendor_Module::admin/resetforgottenpassword.phtml" />
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

The new block just need to have a different name than "content".

```
//File app/code/Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/templates/admin/resetforgottenpassword.phtml
<form method="post" data-mage-init='{"form": {}, "validation": {}}' action="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getUrl('*/auth/resetpasswordpost', ['_query' => ['id' => $block->getRequest()->getParam("id"), 'token' => $block->getRequest()->getParam("token")]]) ?>" id="reset-password-form" autocomplete="off">    <fieldset class="admin__fieldset">
        <legend class="admin__legend"><span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Reset a Password') ?></span></legend><br />
        <input name="form_key" type="hidden" value="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getFormKey() ?>" />
        <div class="admin__field _required field-password">
            <label class="admin__field-label" for="password"><span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('New Password') ?></span></label>
            <div class="admin__field-control">
                <input type="password" class="admin__control-text" data-validate="{required:true, 'validate-admin-password':true}" name="password" id="password" placeholder="new password" autocomplete="off" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="admin__field _required field-confirmation">
            <label class="admin__field-label" for="confirmation"><span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Confirm New Password') ?></span></label>
            <div class="admin__field-control">
                <input type="password" class="admin__control-text" data-validate="{required:true, 'validate-cpassword':true}" name="confirmation" id="confirmation" placeholder="confirm new password" autocomplete="off" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-actions">
            <div class="actions">
                <button type="submit" title="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Reset Password') ?>" class="action-reset action-primary"><span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Reset Password') ?></span></button>
            </div>
            <div class="links">
                <a class="action-back" href="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getUrl('adminhtml', ['_nosecret' => true]) ?>"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Back to Sign in') ?></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

In the original template file the funtions "getResetPasswordLinkToken" and "getUserId" does not exist in the block.

I hope this helps you

Comment: are you sure ? this file because i have implement your code my side but not working for me can you here post full code and here name = "contentt" here tt two time taken

Comment: I'm sure, that's all. Did you enable the module, cleared the cache ?

Comment: I have this in a huge module, I can't add juste this part. Do you have an error in the log files  ? I have also overloaded resetforgottenpassword.phtml

Comment: @RakeshDonga I have added more information

Comment: Thanks Man it's working :)

Comment: Thanks, it is working.

Comment: I'm not sure what caused this exactly(using M 2.4.5-p1) but this solution worked for me.